# How to solve Key error in Jupytor notebook

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I saw a project that uses `Fruit360 dataset` and tried to run the code. I have imported all the libraries but got an error while compiling the code. Can you please help me solve this?

THE CODE:

```
Test_label_ids = np.array([label_to_id_dict[x] for x in Test_labels])
```

THE Error Message:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c5a5039c5bdd> in <module>
----> 1 Test_label_ids = np.array([label_to_id_dict[x] for x in Test_labels])

<ipython-input-15-c5a5039c5bdd> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 Test_label_ids = np.array([label_to_id_dict[x] for x in Test_labels])

KeyError: 'C:\\Users\\Msi\\Desktop\\KaggleDataset\\fruits-360_dataset\\fruits-360\\Test\\Apple Braeburn'
```

Comment: What are the contents of `Test_labels`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, KeyError Occurs in Python when you use a key which doesn't exist in Dictionary which you have created, you can try out Following

```
from collections import defaultdict
ans=defaultdict(int)
#ans=defaultdict(default_factory)
```

when you create a dictionary using  deafultdict
it will never generate the key error
it will give output as zero when you use int as a default factory,
if you use a list instead of int it will return an empty list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried implementing the code but it throws the same error.